# dokku - giving another user root access

Tags: authentication, server, settings, admin, dokku

I added another user's public `ssh-key` to my dokku server, but they can't login using `ssh root@appname.com`.

I can see their ssh-key in `authorized_keys` and also if I run `sshcommand list dokku` or `sshcommand list root`.

I have checked in the `sudoers` config, and it seems that all ssh-keys are given root permissions:

```
$ cat sudoers
/...
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

I am using the [dokku-acl plugin](https://github.com/dokku-community/dokku-acl), but haven't found anything in the docs that would help.

The server is an Aliyun ECS (China).

Feel like I am missing something simple. Any advice is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`root` ssh access and `dokku` ssh access are governed separately. The user's public key should be added *as is* to the `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` file, whereas the `/home/dokku/.ssh/authorized_keys` file should *only* be managed by the subcommands of the `ssh-keys` plugin (included with Dokku).

You may wish to remove the entries from both files manually, then add the entries back as described above. For dokku user access - which would grant the ability to push code as well as perform remote commands via `ssh dokku@host $command` - you can use the command `dokku ssh-keys:add` to add a specific user:

```sh
echo "PUBLIC_KEY_CONTENTS" | dokku ssh-keys:add some-user-name
```